# Coping with alienation in high school in adult life?

Tags: friends

I spent most of my high school isolating myself. Mostly watching anime and being alone. I was always too afraid to get close to anyone, and now that it has been years since high school, I want to reconnect with those people. Maybe one of those reasons I pushed others away is because I am bisexual, and was afraid of letting people know that. 
How do I start being social? I missed my shot at growing my social skills in high school, so I need somewhere in the adult world to branch out and grow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this sound more like an inTRApersonal question (changing yourself) than an inTERpersonal one. Please, see here for what is on-topic here: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic